# Run a rails query in batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, database-cursor

I have a table `A(:name, :address, :phone)` consisting of 500,000 entries. I want to run this query :

```
johns = A.where(:name => "John")
```

This query should return 150,000 results. But running this query gives me this result : `Killed`.

How should I rewrite this query so that the query runs on batches of 1000 in the database?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) with the option *batch_size*.

```
A.where(:name => "John").find_each(batch_size: 1000) do |a|
  # your code
end
```

Comment: I did this. The rake task is still running. But it is printing the following on the terminal in every line. [1432551600, 1432553400, 1432555200, 1432557000, 1432558800, 1432560600, 1432562400]. Any idea what could it be?

Comment: What you gave it to print ?... I think those are Ruby object_id

Comment: I gave nothing to print

Answer (score 12):

An alternative to using `find_each` is to use `find_in_batches`.

There's a distinct difference - `find_each` will give your block each item and will loop through your batch item by item. `find_in_batches` will deliver your batch of items in an array to your block.

I've assumed your `A` model is actually called `Address`. You could do something like this:

```
Address.where(name: "John").find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |addresses|

  # Your code that you might want to run BEFORE processing each batch ...

  addresses.each do |address|
    # Your code that you want to run for each address
  end

  # Your code that you might want to run AFTER processing each batch ...

end
```

As you can see, this gives you a little more flexibility around how you handle the processing of your batches. However, if your needs are simple, just stick with `find_each`.

Comment: Note: `find_each` uses `find_in_batches` internally.

Answer (score 6):

### `.in_batches`

The issue with `find_each` or `find_in_batches` is that you have consumed query results.

**The cleanest solution is using `in_batches`, because it yield the actual query (without consuming it):**

```rb
User.find_in_batches do |users|
  users.select(:id) # error
end

User.in_batches do |users|
  users.select(:id)                   # works as expected
  users.pluck("complext pluck query") # works as expected
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 A.where(:name => "John").find_each(batch_size: 1000) do |a|
    # your code
 end
```